# How can I make the document title bold and larger in size?

Tags: latex

I have this LaTeX code and I was wondering how can I make the document title bold and larger in size than the default size.

```
\documentclass{article}

\title{Document Title}
    
\begin{document}

\maketitle

The content of the document goes here.    

\end{document}
```

I've noticed that `\maketitle` renders the content that is specified above in the preamble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could redefine `\@maketitle`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\title{Document Title}

\makeatletter
\def\@maketitle{%
  \newpage
  \null
  \vskip 2em%
  \begin{center}%
  \let \footnote \thanks
    {\Huge\bfseries\@title \par}%
    \vskip 1.5em%
    {\large
      \lineskip .5em%
      \begin{tabular}[t]{c}%
        \@author
      \end{tabular}\par}%
    \vskip 1em%
    {\large \@date}%
  \end{center}%
  \par
  \vskip 1.5em}
\makeatother
    
\begin{document}

\maketitle

The content of the document goes here.    

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I remember reading somewhere that redefining the maketitle is not a good practice. What's your opinion on that? I find it strange that my first level heading (or section in LaTeX terms) is bigger in size than the document title itself, though. For first level headings I use the `titlesec` package with `{\\normalfont\\huge\\bfseries}{\\thesection}{1em}{}`

Comment: Yes, it is indeed strange to redefine section level headings to be sooooo big. I would make them smaller than title. I don't see any problem in redefining `\@maketitle`.